# awk print from nth column to last

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to print all columns from `nth` to `last` column of a line

### Input String in file

```
vddp vddpi vss cb0 cb1 cb2 cb3 ct0 ct1 ct2 ct3
```

### Command

```
cat <file> | awk ' { for (i=3; i<=NF; i++)   print $i }'
```

### Current Output

```
cb0
cb1
cb2
cb3
ct0
ct1
ct2
ct3
```

### Desired Output

```
cb0 cb1 cb2 cb3 ct0 ct1 ct2 ct3
```

I am trying the [awk](https://awk.js.org/) iteration, but cannot get desired output

Comment: You almost got it. You may change `print $i` to `printf $i" "`.  Full command looks like `echo vddp vddpi vss cb0 cb1 cb2 cb3 ct0 ct1 ct2 ct3  | awk ' { for (i=3; i<=NF; i++)   printf $i" " }'`

Answer (score 17):

```
awk -v n=4 '{ for (i=n; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)}' input
```

This will take n as the value of `n` and loop through that number through the last field `NF`, for each iteration it will print the current value, if that is not the last value in the line it will print `OFS` after it (space), if it is the last value on the line it will print `ORS` after it (newline).

```
$ echo 'vddp vddpi vss cb0 cb1 cb2 cb3 ct0 ct1 ct2 ct3' |
> awk -v n=4 '{ for (i=n; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)}'
cb0 cb1 cb2 cb3 ct0 ct1 ct2 ct3
```

Answer (score 17):

Doesn't answer your question using the `awk` approach requested, but I'll just point out that `cut` can be employed for this task.

```
cut -f4- -d' ' input
```

Comment: `cut` expects one and only one SPC between fields and doesn't ignore leading and trailing ones, while `awk` ignores leading SPC+TABs (sometimes other `[:blank:]`, sometime including newline, sometimes all of ASCII `[:space:]`) and treats *sequences* of one or more whitespace as delimiter.

Answer (score 8):

command

```
awk '{$1=$2=$3="";print $0}' filename| sed -r "s/^\s+//g"
```

command

```
cb0 cb1 cb2 cb3 ct0 ct1 ct2 ct3
```

Comment: `awk '{$1=$2=$3=""; $0=$0; $1=$1; print}' file`

Comment: @RudiC you should make that an answer -- it's much better than your answer above ;-)

Comment: @mosvy : yes, thank you - but it is not mine; don't want to steal an idea.

Comment: The best and the shortest answer found so far awarded to @RudiC

Comment: @RudiC am I wrong in thinking you don't need the `$0=$0` and the `$1=$1`? Assigning any value to any of the fields (as you do when you set the first 3 to empty string) is supposed to rebuild the whole line, so `$0` should have the correct value already. Seems to work that way in my tests.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to preserve the spacing in between the fields that are going to be preserved, you might as well do:

```
<file awk '{sub(/^[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+){3}/, ""); print}'
```

(though note that not all `awk` implementations support `{3}` even though it's POSIX).

That is use a regular expression that matches the first 3 fields.

Or simply use `sed` to do that:

```
<file sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\{3\}//'
```

Another approach with `sed` is:

```
<file sed 's/[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]*/\
/3; s/.*\n//'
```

Which replaces the 3<sup>rd</sup>  field and the blanks following it with a  newline and then deletes everything up to that newline.

Those assume that all the lines in the input have at least 4 fields.

On a `a b c  d <tab>e  f <nl>` input, that will give `d <tab>e  f <nl>` output.

Comment: ...and quietly lurking in the forest was the right answer :-). The awk command should be using `sub()` instead of `gsub()` but no real harm done other than to make some of us pause to think about why it's using gsub()!

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks. good point about gsub. I've replaced it with sub.

Answer (score 4):

An improvement on the `$1=$2=$3=""` trick which works with *any* `FS` or `OFS`, provided that normalizing the output line to `$4 OFS $5 OFS ...` is acceptable:

```
awk 'BEGIN{p=length(OFS)*3+1} {$1=$2=$3="";print substr($0,p)}'
```

Assigning a value to any field (eg. `$1=""` or `$1=$1`) will cause `$0` (the whole record/line) to be rebuilt (the first time it is used) by joining the `$1`, `$2`, ... fields with the `OFS` variable.

So `$1 = $2 = $3 = ""` will have the effect of setting `$0` to `OFS OFS OFS $4 OFS $5 ...`, and the `substr` will get rid of leading `OFS`s (notice that indexes start from 1 in `awk`).

Comment: Collapses blank space between fields.

Answer (score 4):

cut could get you the same result, for example

```
echo "one two three four" | cut -d" " -f 2-
```

this will give you `two three four`, if you were concerned about leading and trailing spaces you could squeezed the spaces with `tr -s " "` for example

```
echo "one    two  three  four   " | cut -d" " -f 2-
```

will give you the same result

Answer (score 3):

with `awk` that supports regex in field separator, you can do:

```
awk -F'^[[:blank:]]*([^ \t]*[ \t]+){3}' '{ print $2 }' infile
cb0 cb1 cb2 cb3 ct0 ct1 ct2 ct3
```

replace number *3* in `{3}` with number of columns you need ignore from the beginning; and space/tab with field separator which your columns delimited with other than whitespaces; so printing `$2` would be the rest of columns remaining to the end; this solution will preserve multiple whitespaces between fields if any in result.

**notes**: to avoid printing empty line if there was a line with equal or less than 3 fields (that indicates the `#` (number) of columns you need cut out) , add `NF>1` to the command.

```
awk -F'^[[:blank:]]*([^ \t]*[ \t]+){3}' 'NF>1{ print $2 }' infile
```

`[[:blank:]]*` is used to avoid erroneous output when FS is whitespaces; if FS is something else (e.x: comma `,`), then the command would be even simpler:

```
awk -F'^([^,]*,){3}' 'NF>1{ print $2 }' infile
```

Comment: Every awk supports a regexp for FS (it's mandated by POSIX and even non-POSIX awks support it). Only gawk supports `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]` though so you should change that or just say its gawk-only. If you keep it then it doesn't make sense to use `\s` in one place and `[ \t]` in another so you can replace the `[ \t]` with `\\s` and `[^ \t]` with `\\S`.

Comment: thanks I have edited with your suggestion but `[[:blank:]]` instead of `[[:space:]]` to match also _tab_ as well as _space_, but I kept using `[ \t]` amd `[^ \t]` since they are representing field seperator and it's to understand where to modify if one's field seperator is something other than whitespaces and only need change ` \t` part there

Comment: You're welcome. If the OP changes to use something other than the default FS then you'd have to get rid of the leading `[[:blank:]]*` too.

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

space-delimited:

```
perl -lane 'print "@F[3..$#F]"' file
```

tab-delimited:

```
perl -F'\t' -lane 'print join "\t", @F[3..$#F]' file
```

Here, the command-line flags are:
`-e`: tells perl interpreter to use the inline code rather than code in file.
`-n`: loops over the input one line at a time, assigning the input line to `$_`.
`-l`: strip the input line separator (new line in UNIX) before the code in the one-liner, and add the output line separator after the `print`.
`-a`: `split` each line in array `@F`, on whitespace by default.
`-F`: `split` on the provided pattern, rather than on whitespace.

`@F[3..$#F]`: fields with indexes from `3` to `$#F` (the last element of `@F`), indexes are zero-based.

Comment: if you're to use perl instead of awk, you can use `split` with a limit and easily preserve the original separators: `perl -nle 'print((split " ", $_, 4)[3])'` or `perl -pe '$_ = (split " ", $_, 4)[3]'`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
awk 'sub ("^" $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS, _)' file
cb0 cb1 cb2 cb3 ct0 ct1 ct2 ct3
```

Comment: Doesn't work with `FS=' '` (the default) when the fields are separated by multiple spaces or tabs or combinations thereof. Also fails with `FS='*'` or `FS='.'`.

Comment: also since first parameter of sub is _regex_ so it will fail if one of columns 1 or 2 or 3 was containing characters other than alpha/num/alnum; for example when a line starts with `[0-9]`

Answer (score 1):

Tried in Python 2:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
k=open('filename','r')
for i in k:
    k=i.strip().split(' ')[3:]
    print " ".join(k)
```

output

```
cb0 cb1 cb2 cb3 ct0 ct1 ct2 ct3
```

Answer (score 1):

print insert a newline by default. Use printf instead of print

```
echo "vddp vddpi vss cb0 cb1 cb2 cb3 ct0 ct1 ct2 ct3" | awk ' { for (i=4; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s " ,$i }'
```

For multiple lines:

```
cat filename.txt | awk ' { for (i=4; i<=NF; i++) 
if (i==NF) 
printf "%s\n", $i
else
printf "%s ", $i
}'
```

Comment: Didn't thought about multiple lines. Added the code for multiple line.

Answer (score 1):

### Retain white space after the field(s) removed:

```
$ sed -E 's/^[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]*){3}//' file
$ awk '{sub(/^[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]*){3}/,"")};1' file
$ grep -oP '^[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]*){3}\K.*' file
```

#### Description

There is a way to match fields with a regex: `[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]+`.
Match an optional stream of blanks (space or tab) followed by an stream of non-blanks. If that pattern is repeated 3 times, 3 fields (with the leading white space) are matched. Then, those could be removed with any tool that is able to process regexes (with variations). Note that there may be white space before and/or after each field, that white space needs to be also matched. Matching any **leading** white space and the delimiting **trailing** white space will make the regex a bit longer: `^[[:blank:]]*([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]*){n}` where n is an integer that points to the last field matched.

Alternative with GNU awk:

```
$ awk -vrem=3 '{ 
                 n=split($0,f,FS,seps);
                 for(i=rem+1;i<=n;i++){
                                        printf("%s%s",$i,seps[i])
                                      };
                 print ""
               }
              '  file
```

## White space collapsed

```
$ awk '{$1=$2=$3=""; $0=$0; $1=$1 } 1 ' file      # thanks RudiC
```